# How to build a gitlab pipeline if my code needs to be ran on a windows server?

Tags: powershell, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, windows-server

I implemented a bunch of infrastructure checks (PowerShell scripts) that need to be ran on Window Servers (most of them use `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet). I put them along with their Pester tests on GitLab and trying to build a pipeline.

I have read [creating-your-first-windows-container-with-docker-for-windows](https://blog.ipswitch.com/creating-your-first-windows-container-with-docker-for-windows) and [building-a-simple-release-pipeline-in-powershell-using-psake-pester-and-psdeploy](https://devblackops.io/building-a-simple-release-pipeline-in-powershell-using-psake-pester-and-psdeploy/) but I am very confused. My understanding is that to have the code run on GitLab CI, I will need to build a Windows Server docker image?

the following is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file but it has authentication errors, the image can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore):

```
image: ltsc2019

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:  
  # run PowerShell script
    - powershell -File "\Deploy\Build.ps1"

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - powershell -File "\Deploy\CodeCoverage.ps1"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - powershell -File "\Deploy\Deploy_Local.ps1"
```

It wouldn't pass the initial build and here are the error I got:

```
# Error 1
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ltsc2019, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:168:3s)

# Error 2 (this happened because I added 'shell: "powershell"' 
# after executor in the gitlab-runner congif file)
ERROR: Preparation failed: Docker doesn't support shells that require script file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ltsc2019` is one tag of the `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore`.

You need to refer this image at the beginning of your .gitlab-ci.yml :

`image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

Comment: Just read [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2936), apparently docker images are not working on docker for Windows... Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who struggles to get docker images working on your Docker for Windows, Please read [Docker executor currently doesn't support Docker for Windows](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2936). Please check out [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/README.html) if you are building a pipeline that needs a container to run it